# I want to create a 3D game in unity for wolf and sheep game. So, how can I set up pieces and move them using C# code?

Tags: unity, c#, 3d

This is the approach that I have made so far in the code that I have written. Based on the output in unity received from the code, I can see 4 white pieces on one end and 4 black pieces on the opposite end. When I try to move the pieces, it moves diagonally once. When I try to move the second piece it goes back to the original settings.
What I am trying to do here is that I want to set up 4 white pieces on one end and 1 black piece on the opposite end and to move them diagonally.
The code is given below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GC : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("The number of squares wide")]
    public int width = 10;
    [Tooltip("The number of squares deep")]
    public int depth = 10;
    [Tooltip("The prefab for the light board tile")]
    public GameObject tileLightPrefab;
    [Tooltip("The prefab for the dark board tile")]
    public GameObject tileDarkPrefab;
    [Tooltip("The prefab for the light playing piece")]
    public GameObject pieceLightPrefab;
    [Tooltip("The prefab for the dark playing piece")]
    public GameObject pieceDarkPrefab;
    [Tooltip("Any string put in messagetext.text will appear the the left of the screen")]
    public Text messageText;
    [Tooltip("Reference to the camera to be used in determining the mouse position")]
    public Camera cam;

    // The following is used if you wish to have mouse input
    private Vector2 mousePos;   // Can be used to hold the mouse screen position 
    private Vector3 mouse3DPos; // Can be used to hold the mouse position on the ground (ignore y axis)
                                // To get the mouse position use the following code in the update method
                                //    mousePos = Input.mousePosition;//gets mouse postion
                                //    // Convert mouse screen position to a position on the ground
                                //    mouse3DPos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, cam.transform.position.y));

    public const int NumberOfPieces = 8;   // A constant used to hold the number of pieces created


    GameObject[] Piece = new GameObject[NumberOfPieces];     // This array will hold all the playing pieces
    Vector3[] Target = new Vector3[NumberOfPieces];       // This array will hold the target for each playing piece

    GameObject[] PiecePrefab = new GameObject[2];   // Used to hold the piece prefabs for easier selection

    public float Speed = 10f;   // Speed to move peice in m/s
    int Movethepiece = 0;        // Used as index to piece array to indicate piece to be moved    
    public float PieceHeight = 0.1f; // The height the pieces should be placed above the tiles

    public enum GameState { Begin, Player1, Player2, End };
    public GameState gameState;
    public bool isGameInitialised = false;
    public Vector3 gizmoPosition = Vector3.zero;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        InitialiseBoard(width, depth);  // Call method to create the playing board
        messageText.text = "";  // Any string assigned to this will appear on the left of the screen 

        PiecePrefab[0] = pieceDarkPrefab;  // Put the pieces prefabs into an array to be able to use the index
        PiecePrefab[1] = pieceLightPrefab;   //  to select a light or dark piece.
        //piece.clear();
        int i = 0;
        while ( i < NumberOfPieces)    // While Loop to initialise the playing pieces
        {
            Target[i] = new Vector3(i, PieceHeight, 0); // Target holds the initial piece position
            Piece[i] = Instantiate(PiecePrefab[i % 2], Target[i], Quaternion.identity);   // Create a new playing piece
            i++;
        }
        
    }
    void InitialGame()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPieces; i++)    // Loop to initialise the playing pieces
        {
            Target[i] = new Vector3(i, PieceHeight, 9 - (i % 2 * 9)); // Target holds the initial piece position
            Piece[i].transform.position = Target[i];
        }
        Target[1] = new Vector3(1f, PieceHeight, 1f);
        Piece[1].transform.position = Target[1];
        isGameInitialised = true;
    } 

    // Method:  InitialiseBoard
    // Input:   int width - the width of the board in number of tiles
    //          int depth - the depth of the board in number of tiles
    // Output:  none
    // Description:
    //      Creates a draughts or checkers board of size given by the inputs.
    //      It assumes that the first tile is at position 0,0 and that the tile are 1x1 in size.
    private void InitialiseBoard(int width, int depth)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)  // Loop through each row of the board
        {                               // x indicates the width position of tile
            for (int z = 0; z < depth; z++) // Loop through each column of the board
            {                               // z indicates the depth position of tile
                // By adding x and z we get a number that alternates between odd and even.
                // Taking the modulus'%' of 2 (i.e. dividing by 2 and taking the remainder)
                // we get a remainder of 0 or 1. We can now check if the number is even by comparing with 0.
                // This allows us to select the light or dark coloured tile to create.
                if ((x + z) % 2 == 0)     // Select light or dark coloured tile. 
                {
                    // Create new instance of Light Tile
                    Instantiate(tileLightPrefab, new Vector3(x, 0, z), Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f));
                }
                else
                {
                    // Create new instance of Dark Tile
                    Instantiate(tileDarkPrefab, new Vector3(x, 0, z), Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        switch (gameState)
        {
            case GameState.Begin:
                Begin();
                break;
            case GameState.Player1:
                MovePiece();
                break;
            case GameState.Player2:
                MovePiece();
                break;
            case GameState.End:
                break;

        }
        //MovePiece();
    }
    void Begin()
    {
        if (!isGameInitialised)
        {
            InitialGame();
        }
        messageText.text = "Wolf and Sheep Game\nInstructions:-\nPress Spacebar Enter to start\nPieces move diagonal only\nLight piece only move forward\n Dark piece move back and forth";
       
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            gameState = GameState.Player1;
        }
    }

    void MovePiece()
    {
        Vector3 tempTarget;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))    // Check for space bar to change piece to be moved
        {
            Movethepiece++;  // Space bar used to increment the piece to be moved
            if (Movethepiece >= Piece.Length)  // check that the piece to moved is valid, i.e. not greater that the pieces available
            {
                Movethepiece = 0;    // If not valid then wrap around to zero.
            }

        }
        if (gameState == GameState.Player1)
        {
            messageText.text = "Player 1\n";
        }
        else
        {
            messageText.text = "Player 2\n";
        }
        messageText.text = "Piece To Move: " + Movethepiece.ToString();  // Tell the play which piece is to be moved.

        tempTarget = Target[Movethepiece];
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            if (tempTarget.z < (width - 1))
            {
                tempTarget.z += 1;
                tempTarget.x += 1;
                if (gameState == GameState.Player1)
                {
                    gameState = GameState.Player2;
                }
                else
                {
                    gameState = GameState.Begin;
                    isGameInitialised = false;
                }
            }

        }
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            if (tempTarget.z > 0)
            {
                tempTarget.z -= 1;
                tempTarget.x -= 1;
                if (gameState == GameState.Player1)
                {
                    gameState = GameState.Player2;
                }
                else
                {
                    gameState = GameState.Begin;
                    isGameInitialised = false;
                }
            }

        }
        Target[Movethepiece] = tempTarget;

        Vector3 position = Piece[Movethepiece].transform.position;
        if (position != tempTarget)
        {
            if (position.z != tempTarget.z)
            {
                if (position.z < tempTarget.z)
                {
                    position.z += Speed * Time.deltaTime;   // Look up LERP
                    if (position.z > tempTarget.z)
                    {
                        position.z = tempTarget.z;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    position.z -= Speed * Time.deltaTime;
                    if (position.z < tempTarget.z)
                    {
                        position.z = tempTarget.z;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Piece[Movethepiece].transform.position = position;
        if (!IsTileOccupied(tempTarget))
        {
            Target[Movethepiece] = tempTarget;
        }

        if (Piece[Movethepiece].transform.position != Target[Movethepiece])
        {
            Piece[Movethepiece].transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Piece[Movethepiece].transform.position, Target[Movethepiece], Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        ShowSelection(Piece[Movethepiece].transform.position);

    }
        public void ShowSelection(Vector3 position)
        {
        gizmoPosition = position;
        }
        public void OnDrawGizmos()
        {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(gizmoPosition, 0.25f);
        }

        public float MoveAxis(float targetAxis, float currentAxis)
        {
        if (currentAxis < targetAxis)
        {
            currentAxis += Speed * Time.deltaTime;   // Look up LERP
            if (currentAxis > targetAxis)
            {
                currentAxis = targetAxis;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentAxis -= Speed * Time.deltaTime;
            if (currentAxis < targetAxis)
            {
                currentAxis = targetAxis;
            }
        }
        return currentAxis;

        }

        bool IsTileOccupied(Vector3 targetTile)
        {
        bool isTileOccupied = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < Target.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Target[i] == targetTile)
            {
                isTileOccupied = true;
            }
        }

        return isTileOccupied;
        }

}
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You want 4 or 1 black piece? Because you write first about 4 black you see and 1 black you want, your code is using assuming 8. (4 black, 4 white)

Comment: 4 black that I mentioned in the output that I got from the code. I actually want to set up 1 black piece on the other end.

Comment: Well, if you want 5 pieces, you should not initialize 8 of them. for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPieces; i++) with NumberOfPieces = 8. Just make 4 for the white pieces and do the black one separately. If you encounter a problem, show how you updated it and maybe a small picture how it looks compared to how it should look.